# Overriding a formula in Excel (getting the % using countif)

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I am hoping someone can help me with my dilemma. I have this formula to calculate the percentage of Yes values. What is also want is to have the value change to Zero(0%) if specific cells are labelled as No.

In D24, below is the formula:

```
=(COUNTIF(D2:D23,"yes")/(COUNTIF(D2:D23,"Yes")+COUNTIF(D2:D23,"No")))
```

If D10 or D20 is equal to No, I want D24 value to automatically return with 0%.

Is this possible?

I cannot seem to find the right formula to override my countif formula. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IF:

```
IF(OR(D10="No",D20="No"),0,(COUNTIF(D2:D23,"yes")/(COUNTIF(D2:D23,"Yes")+COUNTIF(D2:D23,"No"))))
```